# Accordion Image Wrong When Page Loads

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have and issue with an image I have on my Bootstrap accordions.

When the page first loads the accordion image should be an arrow down but it's displaying my arrow up.  The arrow up should be displayed when the accordion is expanded.

If I expand the accordion obviously my image doesn't change but when it closes, it then displays my arrow down as expected and then the image changes as it should do up/down depending on the scenario.

A little hard to explain I know.

**CSS**

```
.panel-heading a:after
{
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e113";
    position: absolute;
    right: 2.5em;
    color: red;
}

.panel-heading a.collapsed:after
{
    content: "\e114";
    color: blue;
}
```

**Accordion HTML**

```
<div id="Generalaccordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Generalaccordion" href="#GeneralcollapseOne">Sub menus</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="GeneralcollapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="mobilesubmenurow">
                    <a runat="server" href="/">One</a>
                </div>
                <div class="mobilesubmenurow">
                    <a runat="server" href="/">Two</a>
                </div>
                <div class="mobilesubmenurow">
                    <a runat="server" href="/">Three</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He gives us all the info, fiddle is not really important here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just add the `collapsed` class ?

**[Fiddle Working](http://www.bootply.com/9r7hZI80Kq)**

**HTML** :

```
<div id="Generalaccordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Generalaccordion" href="#GeneralcollapseOne" class="collapsed">Sub menus</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="GeneralcollapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="mobilesubmenurow">
                    <a runat="server" href="/">One</a>
                </div>
                <div class="mobilesubmenurow">
                    <a runat="server" href="/">Two</a>
                </div>
                <div class="mobilesubmenurow">
                    <a runat="server" href="/">Three</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't believe it was because I was missing my class out, spent nearly an hour trying to figure this out.  Your fix worked great